# "sam local start-api" fails with "invalid volume specification" on (Windows 10 Pro, Docker for Windows)

Tags: aws-sam-cli, aws-sam

I am using SAM CLI 0.6.0 and I am getting the error below when running `sam local start-api` with the app generated using `sam init --runtime java`

```
PS C:\Users\Kiran\AWS\SAM\java-sample\sam-app> sam local start-api
2018-09-03 10:49:49 Mounting HelloWorldFunction at http://127.0.0.1:3000/hello [GET]
2018-09-03 10:49:49 You can now browse to the above endpoints to invoke your functions. You do not need to restart/reload SAM CLI while working on your functions changes will be reflected instantly/automatically. You only need to restart SAM CLI if you update your AWS SAM template
2018-09-03 10:49:49  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:3000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
2018-09-03 10:49:58 Invoking helloworld.App::handleRequest (java8)
2018-09-03 10:49:58 Found credentials in shared credentials file: ~/.aws/credentials
2018-09-03 10:49:58 Decompressing C:\Users\Kiran\AWS\SAM\java-sample\sam-app\target\HelloWorld-1.0.jar

Fetching lambci/lambda:java8 Docker container image......
2018-09-03 10:49:59 Mounting C:\Users\Kiran\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp7f8z0_zj as /var/task:ro inside runtime container
2018-09-03 10:49:59 Exception on /hello [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Kiran\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 229, in _raise_for_status
    response.raise_for_status()
File "C:\Users\Kiran\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 939, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: https://192.168.1.145:2376/v1.35/containers/create

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Kiran\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\Kiran\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\Kiran\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Users\Kiran\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
File "C:\Users\Kiran\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\Kiran\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "C:\Users\Kiran\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\samcli\local\apigw\local_apigw_service.py", line 140, in _request_handler
    self.lambda_runner.invoke(route.function_name, event, stdout=stdout_stream, stderr=self.stderr)
File "C:\Users\Kiran\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\samcli\commands\local\lib\local_lambda.py", line 80, in invoke
    self.local_runtime.invoke(config, event, debug_context=self.debug_context, stdout=stdout, stderr=stderr)
File "C:\Users\Kiran\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\samcli\local\lambdafn\runtime.py", line 79, in invoke
    self._container_manager.run(container)
File "C:\Users\Kiran\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\samcli\local\docker\manager.py", line 61, in run
    container.create()
File "C:\Users\Kiran\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\samcli\local\docker\container.py", line 120, in create
    real_container = self.docker_client.containers.create(self._image, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Kiran\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\docker\models\containers.py", line 824, in create
    resp = self.client.api.create_container(**create_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Kiran\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\docker\api\container.py", line 411, in create_container
    return self.create_container_from_config(config, name)
File "C:\Users\Kiran\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\docker\api\container.py", line 422, in create_container_from_config
    return self._result(res, True)
File "C:\Users\Kiran\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 235, in _result
    self._raise_for_status(response)
File "C:\Users\Kiran\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 231, in _raise_for_status
    raise create_api_error_from_http_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\Kiran\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\docker\errors.py", line 31, in create_api_error_from_http_exception
    raise cls(e, response=response, explanation=explanation)
docker.errors.APIError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error ("invalid volume specification: 'C:\Users\Kiran\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp7f8z0_zj:/var/task:ro'")
2018-09-03 10:49:59 127.0.0.1 - - [03/Sep/2018 10:49:59] "GET /hello HTTP/1.1" 502 -
```

The path mentioned in the last line of the error message (C:\Users\Kiran\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp7f8z0_zj) doesn't seem to exist on my machine. I do have the jar specified code URI of the template file.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
    sam-app

    Sample SAM Template for sam-app

# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
    Function:
        Timeout: 20


Resources:

    HelloWorldFunction:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
        Properties:
            CodeUri: target/HelloWorld-1.0.jar
            Handler: helloworld.App::handleRequest
            Runtime: java8
            Environment: # More info about Env Vars: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#environment-object
                Variables:
                    PARAM1: VALUE
            Events:
                HelloWorld:
                    Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
                    Properties:
                        Path: /hello
                        Method: get

Outputs:

    HelloWorldApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Hello World function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello/"

    HelloWorldFunction:
    Description: "Hello World Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunction.Arn

    HelloWorldFunctionIamRole:
    Description: "Implicit IAM Role created for Hello World function"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunctionRole.Arn
```

Appreciate any inputs to fix this error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Same errors with docker toolbox 
Check out this [issue](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/issues/461).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that issue. I have already checked that issue. But the issue that I am having is with "Docker for Windows" not Docker Toolbox. I was also wondering if the temp path in error message is correct or not. I thought it should be the path to jar file.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in SAM CLI and fixed with latest release.
Do 'Sam --version' and you should see the following.
sam --version
SAM CLI, version 0.6.1.

This issue affected people running SAM on windows 10 with docker toolbox.
Vyas